# Combine VCF files

Tags: r, vcf

I have a problem with using `rbind` to combine VCF files using the library [VariantAnnotation](https://bioconductor.org/packages/VariantAnnotation) from Bioconductor.

I am reading two VCF files, when I try to combine them in a certain order with `rbind` I'm getting an error. When I combine them in a different order, it works fine.

```
vcf.full <- rbind(vcf1, vcf2) ## Doesnt work
```

> Error in as(from, to_class, strict = FALSE) :    no method or default
> for coercing “CompressedCharacterList” to “DNAStringSetList”

```
vcf.full <- rbind(vcf2, vcf1) ## Work 

header(vcf1)
class: VCFHeader 
samples(503): NA06984 NA06989 ... NA20828 NA20832
meta(2): META contig
fixed(2): FILTER ALT
info(27): CIEND CIPOS ... EX_TARGET MULTI_ALLELIC
geno(1): GT

header(vcf2)
class: VCFHeader 
samples(503): NA06984 NA06989 ... NA20828 NA20832
meta(2): META contig
fixed(2): FILTER ALT
info(27): CIEND CIPOS ... EX_TARGET MULTI_ALLELIC
geno(1): GT

dim(vcf1)
[1]  30 503

dim(vcf2)
[1] 149 503
```

The two VCF files seem identical. Any idea of why it happens? Or any suggestions on a different method to combine multiple VCF files using R?

Answer (score 1):

*Answer from @Kozolovska, converted from comment:*

Found the problem, some of ALT were structural variant, so the list of vcf2@info$ALT was a charterer list and not a 'DNAStringSetList' after removing that variant it worked. Thanks.